# Does erasing an element of a std::vector preserve ordering?

Tags: vector

I would like to know if the ordering of the elements of a std::vector container is always preserved after erasing an arbitrary element (for example: push 0,1,2,3, erase 1, get 0,2,3).

Comment: why don't you test it yourself?

Comment: @L7ColWinters: that won't tell him if that just worked that time or if it is actually guaranteed.

Comment: @Mat it will if he does multiple test cases using different primitives

Comment: @L7ColWinters: no. It will just tell him all his tests behaved that way. `char *a = new char[1]; a[1] = 0;` probably won't segfault or cause any noticeable problem on most systems - it is still undefined behavior and can break at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Also make note about the complexity (§ 23.3.6.5):

> Complexity: The destructor of T is called the number of times equal to
>   the number of the elements erased, but the move assignment operator of
>   T is called the **number of times equal to the number of elements in the
>   vector after the erased elements.**

and iterators invalidation:

> Eﬀects: Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of
>   the erase.

If you do not want to look through the standard to check such details and do not feel confident then have a look at this [reference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).